# Switch improvement

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have the following switch case but at the moment is contains 10 conditions.

```
public function convertParameters(string $key, $value)
{
    switch ($key) {
        case "office":
        case "name":
        case "first_name":
        case "last_name":
            $value = ucfirst($value);
            break;
        case "email":
            $value = strtolower($value);
            break;
        case "street":
        case "city":
            $value = ucwords($value);
            break;
        case "start":
        case "end":
            $value = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $value);
            break;
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Does anyone know how i can improve this function so it has less conditions? (or other improvements)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your logic, minus the rogue backslash `\\`. Is your code stifling to normalize the input?

Comment: You could add a `default` case for the most common behaviour, but only you can say if that makes sense for your situation. This looks fine to me.

Comment: Is this broken in any way, shape or form? If not and needs reviewing, go to [codereview.se], we help fix code, they help improve it

Comment: Thanks for your input, no the code is working fine, added use DateTime; to get rid of the backslash, but scrutinizer is giving this a B rating, was wondering how i could improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks fine, but if you're looking for alternatives you can use an array that maps from keys to functions.

```
$ops = [
    "office" => "ucfirst",
    "name" => "ucfirst",
    "first_name" => "ucfirst",
    "last_name" => "ucfirst",
    "email" => "strtolower",
    "street" => "ucwords",
    "city" => "ucwords",
    "start" => function($d) { return DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $d); },
    "end" => function($d) { return DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $d); }
];

if (isset($ops[$key])) {
    return $ops[$key]($value);
} else {
    return $value;
}
```